# Yii 1.1 TbGridView custom pagination

Tags: javascript, yii

I have a following issue with my Yii 1.1 project. I have **bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView** widget in it and 2 buttons. I wan't to use these 2 buttons for `TbGridView` pagination (using JavaScript). How can I handle it?

Here is the code:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'id'=>'doc-to-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'summaryText'=>'{start}-{end}/{count}');
```

Buttons

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default "><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default "><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If could be useful to you the simplest way for pagination is the uso a pager ..this  set pagination like twitter bootstrap

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'template' => "{pager}\n{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}",
 'pager'=>array(            //  pager like twitter bootstrap 
        'header'=>'',
        'cssFile'=>false,
        'maxButtonCount'=>24,
        'selectedPageCssClass'=>'active',
        'hiddenPageCssClass'=>'disabled',
        'firstPageCssClass'=>'previous',
        'lastPageCssClass'=>'next',
        'firstPageLabel'=>'<<',
        'lastPageLabel'=>'>>',
        'prevPageLabel'=>'<',
        'nextPageLabel'=>'>',
),
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I wanted to use other buttons with JavaScript. Because I will use these buttons on other places. Anyway, a big thank you :-)